# Audacity command line batch tempo modification

Tags: batch, audacity

I am using Audacity to speed up my podcast in order to save time while listening to them in the car. Is it possible to create a batch which assigns a given speed (e.g. 30) to all files in a folder?

Answer (score 1):

Audacity doesn't have a (native) CLI !

However, you can do that with `ffmpeg`.

Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

For example

```
ffmpeg -i ./input.mp3 -filter:a "atempo=1.3" -vn ./output.mp3
```

The `1.3` means 130% of tempo.

---

EDIT: A quick script to do this for a lot of files.

I would suggesting not overwriting the originals, but rather make new files in the directory `faster`

```
mkdir /home/user/your/music/directory/faster
```

use your favorite editor

```
nano quick_casts.sh
```

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user/your/music/directory

for f in *.mp3
do echo $f
ffmpeg -i "$f" -filter:a "atempo=1.3" -vn "faster/$f" -y
done
```

Change it to your directories, of course. I've also added "-y" to *always overwrite* files of the same name that exist in the directory `faster`.

make it executable

```
chmod +x quick_casts.sh
```

Comment: Merci je vais tester tout ca

Comment: @JohannLuyat, please accept the answer or describe any issues you have with it